# How do I prevent prevent multiple instances of the same window opening?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently using tkinter to create a GUI for my program. If I open the golf quiz window and open the help window, then close the golf quiz window and re-open it, I am able to click the help window button and open another instance of the help button. How do I set the Help button to be disabled while the Help window is open?

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

class Welcome_Screen:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.welcome_screen_frame = Frame(width=200, height=200, pady=10)
        self.welcome_screen_frame.grid()

        self.quiz_welcome_screen_label = Label(self.welcome_screen_frame, text = "quiz game", font="Arial 20 bold", padx=10)
        self.quiz_welcome_screen_label.grid(row=0)

        self.welcome_screen_buttons_frame = Frame(self.welcome_screen_frame)
        self.welcome_screen_buttons_frame.grid(row=2)

        self.golf_quiz_welcome_screen_button = Button(self.welcome_screen_buttons_frame, text="Golf Quiz", font="Arial 10 bold", command=self.golf_quiz_game, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.golf_quiz_welcome_screen_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5)
    
    def golf_quiz_game(self):
        get_golf_quiz_game = golf_quiz_game(self)

class golf_quiz_game:
    def __init__(self, partner):

        partner.golf_quiz_welcome_screen_button.config(DISABLED)

        self.golf_quiz_box = Toplevel()
        
        self.golf_quiz_box.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', partial(self.close_golf_quiz_game, partner))

        self.golf_quiz_frame = Frame(self.golf_quiz_box)
        self.golf_quiz_frame.grid()

        self.golf_quiz_heading = Label(self.golf_quiz_frame, text="Golf Quiz game",
                                 font="arial 18 bold", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.golf_quiz_heading.grid(row=0)


        self.golf_quiz_history_help_dismiss_buttons_frame = Frame(self.golf_quiz_frame)
        self.golf_quiz_history_help_dismiss_buttons_frame.grid(row=6, pady=10)

        self.help_button = Button(self.golf_quiz_history_help_dismiss_buttons_frame, text="Help", font="Arial 10 bold",command=self.Help, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.help_button.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=5)


    def close_golf_quiz_game(self, partner): 
        partner.golf_quiz_welcome_screen_button.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.golf_quiz_box.destroy()

    def Help(self):
        get_help = Help(self)

class Help:
    def __init__(self, partner):

        partner.help_button.config(state=DISABLED)
         
        self.help_box = Toplevel()

        self.help_box.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', partial(self.close_Help, partner))

        self.help_frame = Frame(self.help_box)
        self.help_frame.grid()

        self.help_heading = Label(self.help_frame, text="Help", font="arial 18 bold")
        self.help_heading.grid(row=0)

        self.help_text = Label(self.help_frame, text="Test",
                                  width=60, wrap=400)
        self.help_text.grid(row=1)

        self.help_button = Button(self.help_frame, text="Dismiss", width=10, font="Arial 10 bold", command=partial(self.close_Help, partner), padx=10, pady=10)
        self.help_button.grid(row=2, pady=10)

    def close_Help(self, partner):

        if partner.help_button.winfo_exists():
            partner.help_button.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.help_box.destroy()        

# main routine
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("quiz game")
    something = Welcome_Screen(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this is not a [mre], I know that it in your case can certainly be reduced to like 50 lines of code tops, it is pretty simple, just remove everything that doesn't cause the issue (it may also help you help the issue yourself)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do that (this is also the size (linewise (approx.)) of the minimal reproducible example which you should have provided):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button


def close_top(top):
    btn.config(state='normal')
    top.destroy()


def open_help():
    btn.config(state='disabled')
    top = Toplevel(root)
    top.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda: close_top(top))
    top.focus_force()
    # put the rest of help stuff here


root = Tk()

btn = Button(root, text='Help', command=open_help)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Class based approach:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button


# this would be the window from where you open the help window
class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.btn = Button(self, text='Help',
                          command=lambda: self.open_help(self.btn))
        self.btn.pack()

    def open_help(self, btn):
        HelpWindow(self, btn)


# this would be the help window
class HelpWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, button):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.button = button
        self.button.config(state='disabled')
        self.focus_force()
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.close)

    def close(self):
        self.button.config(state='normal')
        self.destroy()


MainWindow().mainloop()
```

Few things:
First of you can simply inherit from container and window classes that way you don't have to separately create them in the class and you can easily reference them in the class using just `self`
`.focus_force()` does what it says, it forces focus on the widget

**Important** (suggestions)
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but use if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your help.  I'm having a hard time understanding on what you exactly added and how I can add it to my code because of its different format (I'm a freshman who only very recently started coding). Is the top function equivalent to my welcome screen class or my golf quiz class? What is top_focus_force()?

Comment: @JeffersonAeroplane I added a class based approach solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of *class variables* inside `golf_quiz_game` in order to have only one instance of `Help` window:

```py
class golf_quiz_game:
    # class variables
    _help_button = None   # reference to instance "Help" button
    _help_win = None      # reference to instance "Help" window

    def __init__(self, partner):
        ...

        # set button state based on whether "Help" window is open or not
        self.help_button.config(state="normal" if self.__class__._help_win is None else "disabled")
        # update class reference of "Help" button
        self.__class__._help_button = self.help_button

    def close_golf_quiz_game(self, partner):
        partner.golf_quiz_welcome_screen_button.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.golf_quiz_box.destroy()
        # update class reference of "Help" button
        self.__class__._help_button = None

    def Help(self):
        if self.__class__._help_win is None:
            # no "Help" window is open, create one
            self.__class__._help_win = Help(self)

    def help_closed(self):
        if self.__class__._help_button:
            # enable the "Help" button
            self.__class__._help_button.config(state="normal")
        # update "Help" window status
        self.__class__._help_win = None

class Help:
    ...

    def close_Help(self, partner):
        self.help_box.destroy()
        # notify partner that "Help" window is closed
        partner.help_closed()
```